# Access method argument in asynchronous callback

Tags: angular, typescript

I have code like this..

```js
 getDataTable(callBackFn? : Function)
    {
      this.myHTTPServicet.getServerData("someURL").subscribe((data) => {
     //Do some processing...
     //Do more processing..

     //finally notify the callback, the jobs done.
      if(callBackFn)
       callBackFn();
    });
   }

getDataTable(() => console.log("Called"));
```

Problem:
I am trying to access the callback argument inside subscribe callback.
I perfectly understand that the problem is with the scope here. However, since its a legacy code and its used most of the places; i can not change the method in anyway completely.
Neither i wish to make the argument global scope too.

So how to access the argument value in callback? 
What other ways i can go about?

Kindly help..
Thanks

Comment: You should be able to access the callback function. Which error did you get? If the code about is typescript, it won't be compiled because `function` keyword and the `callBackFn` type definition are missing.

Comment: Hi, This is an angular project. So yes its a TS code. 
The if block never executes coz when the callback gets invoked, the callbackfunction variable is undefined. 

I have edited the code for the argument to have a specific type. Still wont work.

Answer (score 0):

The parent function arguments are available inside the child callback, because they are caught by the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). The problem isn't here.

The code in your sample should work, if the subscribe callback is called. Try to replace the server call by `setTimeout()` for example, it will work.

```js
function getDataTable(callBackFn: () => void) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Do some processing...
    // Do more processing..

    // finally notify the callback, the jobs done.
    if (callBackFn) {
        callBackFn();
    }
  });
}

getDataTable(() => console.log("Called !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"));
```

Comment: Actually you are right. I tried an example and it works there, with the same set of liberaries and deps on both projects. Only problem is, i am unable to understand why it doesnt work on my large project.. but works fine on the sample example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-callback-test 
I even copied the example code to actual project, it wont work :(

Comment: The stackblitz example doesn't work for some reason, it just writes "Starting dev server". In the example code, you execute `callBackFn` from the third argument of the `subscribe`, which is called only when the observable is completed. Maybe the observable that `getData` returns isn't completed in your real project?. Did you tried to add a log in place of the callback call, to be sure, the code is executed?

Comment: Sometimes the stackblitz has issues. Not sure why. 

Regarding adding log to check if my http call gets hits, yes it does. I also have logged in the subscribe callback, it hits. Since it is a GET call, it should automatically gets completed, isnt it? Not sure how to make it completed. The backend is a cloud based services :(

Comment: @Zenwalker Maybe you can add more code of your real app to the question? It would be easier to solve the problem.

Comment: Apparently i am not suppose to add any actual code here. Violation of company terms. 
Hence added a similar simulation code. All i can mention here is that, the frontend is angular app, the backend is a springboot app running on a AWS cloud. Not sure if this has anything to do with incomplete observables?

Comment: @Zenwalker Unfortunately, the code you demonstrated isn't enough to help you. The problem is outside of that code. Any rxjs observable can be completed or not, the third `subscribe` callback is called only when the observable is completed and it doesn't depend on the backend you use. Anyway, if you've checked that the code is executed, it isn't your case.

Comment: AFAIK when a remote call is made (http get) via a service, and when you subscribe to the observable as i have shown the code; then everything should go smooth.. Thats what my understanding is. 
So i do get the subscribe call back hit and i made sure that there is no errors and tried to log for all http related errors. None. Still complete call back isnt called. 
Does that means, the connection is not closed at server end? Depends on response headers to keep it alive?